# VBA =Left() Function

Tags: vba

Lets keep it simple and avoid computer talk

Here's my data

```
Source location is Column D = "USA, TX"
Destination Location is Column E.
```

I need to get the country "USA" into Column E from Column D. In simple basic formula it would be

```
=Left(D,3)
```

But what is this in VBA?

Comment: `Range("E2").value = Left(Range("D2"),3)`

Comment: Scott, how do I make the statement if column D has a cell range value from D2 through D whatever, since the data is going to be dynamic on a daily basis, the cell range of column D could vary from 200 to 2000.

Comment: google how to find the last row and loop through the cells in a column.

Comment: [Find last row and loop through range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42103873/6706419)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this. Code is untested (written on mobile).

```
Option Explicit

Sub extractCountries()
    Dim arrayOfValues() as variant
    Dim lastRow as long
    Dim rowIndex as long
    'Change these four lines as needed ' 
    Const SOURCE_COLUMN as string = "D"
    Const DESTINATION_COLUMN as string = "E"
    Const ROW_TO_START_FROM as long = 1
    With thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .cells(.rows.count, SOURCE_COLUMN).end(xlup).row
        arrayOfValues = .range(SOURCE_COLUMN & ROW_TO_START_FROM ":" & SOURCE_COLUMN & lastRow).value2
        For rowIndex = lbound(arrayOfValues,1) to ubound(arrayOfValues,1)
            arrayOfValues(rowIndex,1) = vba.strings.left$(arrayOfValues(rowIndex,1),3)
            'If the logic should be "everything before the comma", use instr() function above.'
        Next rowIndex
        .range(DESTINATION_COLUMN & ROW_TO_START_FROM ":" & DESTINATION_COLUMN & lastRow).value2 = arrayOfValues
    End with
End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
Dim s As String = "USA, TX"
s = Strings.Left(s, 3)
```