# Excel VBA code broke after row number 1020 (continue in diferent cells)

Tags: vba, excel

i have a problem with my vba code. i have to generate a line and point numbers for my survey and grab a coordinate for that points from another txt file. It work fine until row number 1020, after that point, formula can't find a first empty cell in column, and insted continue to write data to first column.

my formula to find a first empty cell in column is

```
Worksheets("POSTAVLJANJE").Activate
        NextFree = Range("B3:B" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
        Range("B" & NextFree).Select
```

any idea?

Comment: xlCellTypeBlanks returns all the blank cells, not just one.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065840/meaning-of-cells-rows-count-a-endxlup-row/27066381#27066381

Comment: SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) will ignore the empty cells after the last used cell in column B. Are you sure you have an empty cell in column B before the last row with data in column B?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Last not empty cell in row; Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872512/last-not-empty-cell-in-row-excel-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this instead:

```
NextFree = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row+1
```

This will find the first non empty row starting from the bottom, and add one to indicate the first row below that.